# Gradient of an Inner Product in a more general Vector Space

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inner-products

I was looking at the following question:

[Differentiating an Inner Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96265/differentiating-an-inner-product)

that was talking about the derivative of an inner product to be:

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \langle f, g \rangle = \langle f(t), g^{\prime}(t) \rangle + \langle f^{\prime}(t), g(t) \rangle
$$

However, I was looking for a more general answer when $f$ and $g$ belong to a more general Vector Space. In that case does the equivalent conjecture hold?

$$
\bigtriangledown_w \langle w, x \rangle = \langle w, \bigtriangledown_wx \rangle + \langle \bigtriangledown_ww, x \rangle
$$

I believe the above does not hold and that it needs some slight modification to make it work. Does someone know what this modification might be? What is the gradient of a more general inner product.

Comment: I do not see what is more general in your question compared with the linked one.

Comment: taking the gradient and taking the derivative wrt to one variable are different things ... Right?

Comment: w might be in a vector space of functions, is what I believe makes my question more general. Intuitively, it has more dimension I guess.