# Riemann Manifold equipped with Euclidean metric

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, connections

I am trying to understand the following equations about the Euclidean metric:

1. $g_p = dx^1 \otimes dx^1 + \dots +dx^n \otimes dx^n$
2. $X_p\cdot g_p (Y_p,Z_p) = g_p(\bar{\nabla}_{X_p}Y_p,Z_p) + g(Y_p, \bar{\nabla}_{X_p}Z_p)$

About 1. I thing I got it if you thought $g_p$ as an element of the space defined by the tensor product of the cotangent spaces $T^*M \otimes_{M} T^*M = \bigcup\limits_{p \in M} T^*_pM \otimes T^*_pM$. 2. seems line [differentiating inner product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96265/differentiating-an-inner-product) but how can we prove it with $X_p$ applied as a derivation to a smooth manifold?

Thanks.
Could you please help to prove 2. analytically?

Comment: It is not clear what is to he proved. It seems that 1 is just stating the definition, and 2 is an property of the connection  and there is no 3.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was wondering If someone could prove 2. and if it is possible to relate it with the differentiation of the inner product in the given link. PS: Sorry about 3. mistake.

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\bar \nabla _{X_p} Y_p$?

Comment: $\bar{\nabla}_{X_p} Y_p=X_p(Y_p)=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\mathcal{X}^i(p)\frac{\partial\mathcal{Y}^j}{\partial x_i} \Bigr|_{p}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Bigr|_{p}$, where $\mathcal{X}_i,\mathcal{Y}_j \in \mathbb{R}$ the coordinate coefficients of vector fields $X_p,Y_p$, respectively. Is there any specific property of $g_p$ which can be used along with $\bar{\nabla}_{X_p}Y_p$ definition?

Comment: Yes  you've got the correct definition. Then (2) is really a direct calculations.

Comment: I think I got it, cold you please verify my answer? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x^1, \dots, x^n)$ a local coordinate system and
$$X_p = \sum_i \mathcal{X}_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Biggr|_p,$$
$$Y_p = \sum_i \mathcal{Y}_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Biggr|_p,$$
$$Z_p = \sum_i \mathcal{Z}_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Biggr|_p.$$ vector fields.
Moreover, for a Riemann metric $g$ we have

$$g(Y_p,Z_p) = \sum_{ij} \mathcal{Y}^i_p\mathcal{Z}^j_p g_{ij}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Biggr|_p, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Biggr|_p\right).$$.

In addition, for two vector fields $Y_p,Z_p$ the Euclidean connection $\bar{\nabla}_{X_p}Y_p$ is given by

$$\bar{\nabla}_{X_p}Y_p = \sum_j X_p(\mathcal{Z}^j)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Biggr|_p$$

Now apply $X_p$ as derivation on $g$ and we obtain

$$X_p \cdot g(Y_p,Z_p) = \sum_{i,j}X_p(\mathcal{Y}^i\mathcal{Z}^j)g_{ij}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Biggr|_p, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Biggr|_p\right) = \sum_{i,j}[(X_p\mathcal{Y}^i\mathcal{Z}^j) +\mathcal{Y}^i X_p\mathcal{Z}^j) ]g_{ij}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Biggr|_p, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Biggr|_p\right) = g(\bar{\nabla}_{X_p}Y_p,Z_p) + g(Y_p,\bar{\nabla}_{X_p} Z_p).$$

<sup>Thank @Arctic Char for useful comments.</sup>